# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: react-native

Please help !!!!

I am getting this crash on firebase crashlytics console for react-native android app.
Unable to figure out the exact reason or code responsible.

Any help would be appreciated.

**ReactHorizontalScrollView.java line 750
com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollView.flingAndSnap**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
       at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollView.flingAndSnap(ReactHorizontalScrollView.java:750)
       at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollView.access$300(ReactHorizontalScrollView.java:45)
       at com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollView$1.run(ReactHorizontalScrollView.java:624)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:999)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:728)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: this means you are trying to read a value from an empty array, so you need to check that the array isn't empty before trying to read from it.

Comment: Thanks for replying but how would this translate in terms of react-native.

Comment: It should be a problem with your horizontal `ScrollView`, so please provide the code for that if you know which one it is